# Unable to get Bluetooth MAC addresses on Windows using subprocess or PyBluez

Tags: python

I am attempting to retrieve the MAC addresses of connected Bluetooth devices using Python on a Windows system. I've tried using both the subprocess module with the hcitool command and the PyBluez library, but encountered issues with both approaches.

**1. Using subprocess with hcitool:**

I received the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

which suggests that hcitool is not available on Windows. Is there an alternative command or approach for obtaining Bluetooth information on Windows?

**2. Installing PyBluez:**

When attempting to install PyBluez using pip install pybluez, I encountered the following error during the build process:

```
error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
```

Comment: for issue #2: remove line, don't use `pip`, rather ensure you have dependencies installed and "in setup.py remove use_2to3=True" , etc.https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/issues/431#issuecomment-1107702852